# PHP Data Object failed to connect

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner in PHP and trying to connect with mysql database by creating PDO.
I unable to fetch the data from database as

`Error : Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected`

Code:

```
<?php
$config['db']=array(
                    'host'      =>'localhost',
                    'username'  =>'root',
                    'password'  => '',
                    'dbname'    =>'testing'
                    );
$db= new PDO(
                'mysql:host =   '.$config['db']['host'].';
                 dbname     =   '.$config['db']['dbname'],
                                  $config['db']['username'],
                                  $config['db']['password']
            );


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = "SELECT * from Studentsdetails ";
$Data = $db->prepare($query);
try
    {
    $Data->execute();
    $Show=$Data->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<pre>',print_r($Show),'</pre>';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $e->getMessage();
    //die($e->getMessage());
    echo '<pre>',print_r($e),'</pre>';
    die('Arrrgh!');
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Help me to correct this code.

Comment: I have answered in deep with your code corrected also please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$config['db']['dbname'].';host='.$config['db']['host'];

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
```

Try this you have made mistake in creating the $dsn string

```
<?php
$config['db']=array(
                    'host'      =>'localhost',
                    'username'  =>'root',
                    'password'  => '',
                    'dbname'    =>'testing'
                    );
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$config['db']['dbname'].';host='.$config['db']['host'];
$db= new PDO($dsn, $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = "SELECT * from Studentsdetails ";
$Data = $db->prepare($query);
try
    {
    $Data->execute();
    $Show=$Data->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<pre>',print_r($Show),'</pre>';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $e->getMessage();
    //die($e->getMessage());
    echo '<pre>',print_r($e),'</pre>';
    die('Arrrgh!');
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it's great to find guys like you...
I feel up now..
thanks it's working now..
Thank you very much i get to know where i did the mistake ..
Great Help

Comment: @ManishNegi always happy to help, Please accept the answer if it help you as it will change the question state to answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code for the initialization of PDO object is too confusing. Please try the below code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', 'root', '');
```

Comment: This seems to be a static answers Manoj please use variables in the OP